# AVPlayerRateDidChangeReasonAppBackgrounded called even when app is not in background

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I'm finding that on iOS 15, AVPlayer is adjusting its rate to 0.0 with the notification reason `AVPlayerRateDidChangeReasonAppBackgrounded`, even when the app is still in the foreground.

This seems to occur when a view containing an AVPlayerLayer is removed from the view hierarchy (for example, when a view controller is dismissed).

It seems like the only way to resolve this is to set the AVPlayerLayer's player to `nil` before it is removed from the view hierarchy.

Anyone else experiencing this? Any other workarounds?

Comment: I am facing the same issue in my production App. Looking for a solution.

Comment: @Frankenxtein In that case, you should vote for this question instead of writing this comment, also you can follow it to make sure you won't miss an answer